# SSIS and Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices

Tags: ssis, reference

I am writing an SSIS package that has required me to use the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices DLL. I have imported it into the VB Script Task where it is referenced from the following location:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange\Web Services\2.0\Microsoft.Exchange.WebService.dll

The script task seems to 'like' it in so much that I have imported the Namespace and am able to declare the ExchangeService as an object. However, when it comes to running the package (both compiled and in debug) I get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified.

I have checked the Regedit and can see that the DLL exists there... I am sure I am missing something silly... Is anyone able to help??

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: Permissions on the .dll file/folder?

Comment: Thanks Tab Alleman - I have checked the permissions for the account running the SSIS Service has permissions as well as the account I have logged onto the server and anything else I can think off....?? I hoped yo were on to something but still not running with the same error?? Is there anything else you might look for?

Comment: I am using SSIS In SQL Server 2008 R2... Do you suppose this latest version of the Exchange Web Service might not be compatible?

Comment: Sorry, I have no other ideas.   I'm not an exchange expert.